# Using a Channel Entry as an Embed Template

Tags: templates, channel

Is it possible to have Channel Entry as a text input be used dynamically to include a design template? In other words, something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel" limit="1"}
    {embed="embeds/{myentryfield}"}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

OR some other similar method to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Do you know an embed is a fully parsed template? Why do you wanna do this? Just to avoid to repeat code? If so, there are [better ways](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/template_partials.html) of do that.

Comment: I have a channel that indicates images, videos, text, etc.   But now I have a section with its own HTML.   I want the entry to say "addthistemplate" and it inserts the HTML template

Comment: Is there dynamic content on this embed?

Comment: No, it will be just static html

Comment: It's a matrix...so one column is the type (image,text,video) and the other column is the content (image name, video name, or text)

Comment: So I want "html" type and the static content, which would be just the template name ideally

Comment: You code should work, then. But you don't need exactly to use a template. There's [other option](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/globals/template_variable.html).

Comment: But you still have the same problem, the variable would be named in the channel entry, you can't relate the entry to a variable in the template.

Comment: You could do this:  {embed="embeds/static" content="{myentryfield}"} and use if statements.

Comment: Can you just put HTML in a channel entry textarea?

Comment: Typically mixing content and template logic is not a great idea. Can you expand your original question to include the overall goal rather than the just the implementation question? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: I just added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have a file with html content in a channel entry.  Say the name of the field in the entry is {myfile}.  The value of {myfile} I can choose since in EE.  If it were "/mycontent/myfile.html"

In the template, could you enable PHP and say this:

```
<?php include_once("{myfile}") ?>
```

which would be the same as

```
<?php include_once("/mycontent/myfile.html"); ?>
```

Would that work?